# Webcam and Headset plugged into the same Hub cause one or the other to stop

Tags: drivers, 20.04, usb, webcam, headset

I'm on 20.04 and was hoping to get a workstation working. I am using a powered 4-Port USB Hub which I used on Windows to power a USB to Ethernet Adapter, my USB Dongle that connects to my Wireless Headset (Plantronics) and a USB Webcam (noname).

Plugged into the same, either the Webcam or the Headset cease working completely. Only after unplugging one or the other do I get a response again. The Webcam is also still recognized as plugged in, it simply does not react anymore. Same with the headset.

Plugging them into separate USB ports (one in the hub, one directly in the laptop) seems to solve this issue.

Can there be some explanation on why the Hub ceases functionality in this specific scenario? One other wireless headset (SteelSeries Arctis) did work from the same hub together with the Webcam without a problem, it seems to be this specific device causing issues.

Below lsusb output causes issues

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 13d3:5405 IMC Networks Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 056a:5229 Wacom Co., Ltd Pen and multitouch sensor
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 291a:8324 Anker Anker USB-C Hub Device
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0c45:6366 Microdia USB Receiver
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 047f:02f7 Plantronics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

This right here does not:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 13d3:5405 IMC Networks Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 056a:5229 Wacom Co., Ltd Pen and multitouch sensor
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 291a:8324 Anker Anker USB-C Hub Device
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0c45:6366 Microdia Plantronics BT600
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 047f:02f7 Plantronics, Inc. Plantronics BT600
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: There are other devices in the list you show here not in the question.  Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver

Comment: In scenario 1, the Unifying Receiver is plugged into a completely different port going from the Laptop, in scenario 2, because I only have this one hub, I moved the Headset Receiver to the port the Unifying Receiver was in, and put the Unifying Receiver into the Hub.
Removing or Adding that Receiver does not change anything about the scenario, though.

Comment: My situation was also in two different ports not a hub and the Bluetooth caused problems. Any way good luck I do think you have a hardware conflict not directly a Ubuntu problem.

Comment: Thanks, curious because I was of the opinion it might be a power delivery issue altogether. Seems like I will have to look for alternate routes for now.

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl --follow` as you plug and unplug